# Selenium: Can I hide window after login screen

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I created a bot to sends automatic whatsapp messages. But I have a question I want to hide window after qr code scanned, is this possible without using `--headless` option?

Answer (score 0):

***No*** you can't hide the window once you have initialized the *Browsing Context* in the normal (headed) mode within the same session. Neither you can add the `--headless` option for the same ongoing session.

A cleaner way would be to call **`driver.quit()`** within `tearDown(){}` method to **close** and **destroy** the current *ChromeDriver* and *Chrome Browser* instances gracefully and then span a new set of *ChromeDriver* and *Chrome Browser* instance with the new set of configurations.